# Define proper type for coreceMatM in haskell-opencv

Tags: opencv, haskell, image-processing

I try to understand [haskell-opencv](https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv) library.

And I port orb-detection [example](http://lumiguide.github.io/haskell-opencv/doc/OpenCV-Features2d.html#v:orbDetectAndCompute) for my images:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad
import Linear.V4
import Linear.V2
import OpenCV as CV
import OpenCV.Internal.Mutable
import qualified Data.ByteString as B


main = do
    img <- imdecode ImreadColor <$> B.readFile "input.jpg"
    let orb = mkOrb defaultOrbParams
    let imgData = exceptError $ do
            (kpts, _descs) <- orbDetectAndCompute orb img Nothing
            let mi = matInfo img
                clr = (toScalar $ V4 (255::Double) 255 255 0)::(Scalar)
                shape = toShape $ miShape mi
                chan = toChannels $ miChannels mi
                depth = toDepth $ miDepth mi
            resImg <- withMatM shape chan depth clr $ \imgM -> do
                let img' = exceptError $ coerceMatM imgM
                    img'' = (unMut img'')::CV.Mat ('S ['D, 'D]) 'D 'D
                    img''' = Mut img''
                -- let img''' = (exceptError $ coerceMatM imgM)::(CV.Mut (CV.Mat ('S ['D, 'D]) 'D 'D) (PrimState (ST s)))
                void $ matCopyToM img''' (V2 0 0) img Nothing
                forM_ kpts $ \kpt -> do
                    let kptRec = keyPointAsRec kpt
                    circle img''' (round <$> kptPoint kptRec) 5 (V4 (255::Double) 0 0 255) 1 LineType_AA 0
                    return ()
            imencode OutputBmp resImg
    B.writeFile "output.bmp" imgData
```

Ufff, after two hours of reading documentation, it works!

But I can't understand, how to properly write corecing of Mat and typeing it, my code is very ugly:

```
let img' = exceptError $ coerceMatM imgM
    img'' = (unMut img')::CV.Mat ('S ['D, 'D]) 'D 'D
    img''' = Mut img'
```

I unpack with `unMut` and then pack it back.

I try to specify type of `Mut (Mat ...)` (see commented line above):

```
let img''' = (exceptError $ coerceMatM imgM)
   ::(CV.Mut (CV.Mat ('S ['D, 'D]) 'D 'D) (PrimState (ST s)))
```

But compiler swear:

```
src/exmpl.hs:29:60: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘s2’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s.
          Mut
            (Mat
               (ShapeT (Data.Vector.Vector GHC.Int.Int32))
               (ChannelsT GHC.Int.Int32)
               (DepthT Depth))
            (PrimState (ST s))
          -> CvExceptT (ST s) ()
        at src/exmpl.hs:23:27
      ‘s2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        an expression type signature:
          forall s2. Mut (Mat ('S '['D, 'D]) 'D 'D) (PrimState (ST s2))
        at src/exmpl.hs:29:67
      Expected type: Mut (Mat 'D (ChannelsT GHC.Int.Int32) 'D) s2
        Actual type: Mut
                       (Mat
                          (ShapeT (Data.Vector.Vector GHC.Int.Int32))
                          (ChannelsT GHC.Int.Int32)
                          (DepthT Depth))
                       (PrimState (ST s))
```

So, how to determine right type for `img'''`??

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It's need to use `pureExcept` and scoped type variables:

```
(imgM''':: Mut (Mat (S [D, D]) D D) s) <- pureExcept $ coerceMatM imgM
```

So full program is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad
import Linear.V2
import Linear.V4
import OpenCV as CV
import qualified Data.ByteString as B


main = do
    img <- imdecode ImreadColor <$> B.readFile "input.jpg"
    let orb = mkOrb defaultOrbParams
    let imgData = exceptError $ do
            (kpts, _descs) <- orbDetectAndCompute orb img Nothing
            let mi = matInfo img
                clr = (toScalar $ V4 (255::Double) 255 255 0)::(Scalar)
                shape = toShape $ miShape mi
                chan = toChannels $ miChannels mi
                depth = toDepth $ miDepth mi
            resImg <- withMatM shape chan depth clr $ \imgM -> do
                (imgM':: Mut (Mat (S [D, D]) D D) s) <- pureExcept $ coerceMatM imgM
                void $ matCopyToM imgM' (V2 0 0) img Nothing
                forM_ kpts $ \kpt -> do
                    let kptRec = keyPointAsRec kpt
                    circle imgM' (round <$> kptPoint kptRec)
                                 5
                                 (V4 (255::Double) 0 0 255)
                                 1
                                 LineType_AA
                                 0
                    return ()
            imencode OutputBmp resImg
    B.writeFile "output.bmp" imgData
```